# A SQL Server query that increases the value of everyone's pension fund by one month's worth of contributions

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query issue which I'm struggling with, I am quite new to it.

Basically I have an pension fund and every month Employees will contribute 5% of their wage to it per month.

As I'm in learning I'm finding it quite difficult to figure out what the best type of query (what I mean by the is `INSERT` etc) would be and also what sort of information you guys would want from me to assist? Also using SQL Server Management Studio

Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO CompanyEmployees (FirstName, LastName, Age, Salary, PositionID, PensionID) 
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 33, 30.000, 
           (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
            FROM JobPosition 
            WHERE Title = 'IT Support'),
           (SELECT ID 
            FROM PensionFunds 
            WHERE Amount = 250.00));

INSERT INTO PensionFunds (Amount, PensionProvider) 
VALUES ('250.00', 3)
```

So basically, every month I need "John Doe" to contribute 5% of his 30.000 into his PensionFund.

Hopefully this is what you guys were after. Apologies if the SQL isn't up to scratch.

Comment: What is the SQL engine (Postgres, MySQL, anything other)? Can you give a sample of data? What fields do you have? It is a bit unclear what you want to do.

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: What do you mean with "best type of query"?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: The fact, 3 valid questions have been raised about your question should indicate just how broad your actual question is. Try to be a bit more precise (and by bit I mean by quite a lot)

Comment: Apologies guys on the broadness of my question, Wasn't exactly sure what you guys would need.

Comment: Help us help you.  We can't help you if we don't understand you.  Learn how to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect something like this:

```
INSERT INTO PensionFunds (EmployeeId, Amount, PensionProvider) 
    SELECT EmployeeId, Salary * 0.05, PensionId
    FROM CompanyEmployees;
```

This does not take a zillion things into account, such as:

- Not all rows in `CompanyEmployees` might be active employees.
- Not all rows in `CompanyEmployees` might be contributing to the pension fund.
- There could perhaps be duplicates in `CompanyEmployees` (what if someone has two part-time positions).
- You don't seem to have a date, so you are allowing multiple contributions at the same time.
- Perhaps not all employees contribute 5%.

Comment: At this moment in time. It's as basic as it comes. One job. All Active. All at the same time. All 5%.

Thanks for the time to reply!